# Chatting with Live Agent directly from the website?

Tags: liveagent

So I'm kinda new and skilling up into coding and developing in Salesforce — also here ;) — Live Agent is the first app I work with and it's so interesting!

My lack of experience breaks me a bit and now I'm wondering if including the Live Agent chat page is possible directly within the website.

> Exemple:
>
> An automated invitation button is set: it slides up on the webpage, when the user approach it's mouse the image grow bigger asking the user if he wants to chat with an agent. If the user click, the popup transforms into the Live Agent chat page. Sort of what Olark does actually.

Is that something that can be done with Live Agent?

Thanks for your help!

Niko.

Comment: I have successfully used `liveagnet.startChatWithWindow` solution proposed in [PepeFloyd's answer](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/55299/11611). I'd call this undocumented feature, but works fine.

Answer (score 1):

you're going to have to use a lightbox or something similar, and create a custom visual force page for the pre-chat invitation - which then turns into the chat screen - you wouldn't have to put in the collection fields - you could just show an image if you wanted.

http://iwritecrappycode.wordpress.com/2013/10/29/salesforce-live-agent-review-customization/

There's a GREAT sample of a custom prechat page in visualforce.  Create that, use that as the lightbox page, and then after they click submit there - that lightbox will turn into the chat screen.   It's a little convoluted, but that's how we're doing it.

Answer (score 1):

I had created video tutorial for complete liveagent and how to use generated HTML, hope it will help you.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yBZUoHmAEiM

Comment: Hello Jitendra!! This video was actually the first tutorial I found to understand the Live Agent setup 2 weeks ago. It really help me out back then! I watched it many times!! Thanks a lot for that :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try using an iframe and put your button and deployment code in the iframe, that in combination with the **liveagent.startChatWithWindow** method, which allows you to specify in which window you want to open the chat, could result in something like this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I`m not sure if this is something that you are after but if you have Live Agent enabled in Salesforce, there is a section under Customize - Live Agent - Chat Buttons & Invitations. And there you would have a section called Chat Button Code and that code can be implemented in your website from where the users would have access to it and they can click on the button in order to talk to you.

Once they click on the button a popup window will appear and they will start typing. You could also add your own Live Agent Configurations under Setup -> Live Agent -> Live Agent Configurations, for example the chat capacity, agent name, auto greeting and the profiles that will have access to the Live Agent.

[image]
Hope it helps

Comment: I did all that already. Now I would like to know if it's possible to customise it more. Like the pop-up floating on the page itself and not in a new window or redesigning the cross to close the popup image for exemple. Is all this code accessible?

Comment: I believe that you have to do that in your HTML/CSS/JavaScript code where you can have full control on the appearance of the window or if it slides up, etc.

Comment: Well, I don't know where I can access the live agent configuration code. All I know is when you create a custom chat page you can code a few things there. but it's not so full control...

Comment: You don't need to access the live agent configuration code because you are not trying to modify the functionality. All you probably need is to wrap the code for the chat button with your own style and in your own window. I might not fully understand your requirement. Maybe another person from this site might have a different point of view.

Comment: yes, that's it! I mainly want to intervene on the chat button and window not the functionality itself. But where can I edit the code for the button? Because I would like the button to become the custom chat page once clicked.

Comment: You would go under Customize - Live Agent - Chat Buttons & Invitations. And then you can copy the code from there in your HTML page and start modifying the style but keep intact the functionality.

Comment: Can you be more precise about where I can get the code from on the page? If you think about the Automated Invitation Sample Code
it says:
You don’t need to do anything else! Your custom automated invitation will appear on the deployments you selected.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a screenshot of what you should have in your live agent configuration. The code I was referring is under the Chat Button Code and it`s says: Place this code into your site's HTML where you want the chat button to appear. And that was what I was referring, after you paste the code you will have full control in your HTML to change the look and feel but keep the functionality the same. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Mihai, since my automated invitation is linked to a deployment, can I make these change in the deployment code as well? I guess yes but I rather ask :)

Comment: The Deployment Code just lists some JavaScript files that would give the functionality to the button that I've included in the screenshot. I see no reason why you would change.

Comment: But when I go there, I get this message instead of editable code:

"Automated Invitation Sample Code:
 
You don’t need to do anything else! Your custom automated invitation will appear on the deployments you selected."

Answer (score 0):

If using iFrame is not ideal (not mobile friendly), in the same page file, give it a window name first.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.name = 'chatchat'
</script>
```

Open the chat or pre-chat form within the same window.

```
liveagent.startChatWithWindow('573A0000000XXXX','chatchat')
```